# Why cannot order a factor in data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (named 'mdf') which includes two columns. The basic information is below:

```
> head(mdf); tail(mdf)
  Country Rank
1     ABW  161
2     AFG  105
3     AGO   60
4     ALB  125
5     ARE   32
6     ARG   26
    Country Rank
184     WSM  181
185     YEM   90
186     ZAF   28
187     ZAR  112
188     ZMB  104
189     ZWE  134
> str(mdf)
'data.frame':   189 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Country: Factor w/ 229 levels "","ABW","ADO",..: 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 ...
 $ Rank   : Factor w/ 195 levels "",".. Not available.  ",..: 72 10 149 32 118 111 41 84 26 112 ...
```

My purpose is to rearrange it by ordering 'Rank' variable, but the result is:

```
> mdf[order(mdf$Rank),]
    Country Rank
178     USA    1
78      IND   10
153     SLV  100
170     TTO  101
43      CYP  102
54      EST  103
188     ZMB  104
2       AFG  105
175     UGA  106
130     NPL  107
73      HND  108
60      GAB  109
31      CAN   11
67      GNQ  110
```

As you see, it is not what I need (i.e. increasing order). How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: It appears your variable is a factor, not a numeric. Try `mdf[order(as.numeric(as.character(mdf$Rank))),]`

Comment: It works perfectly! Can you tell me why it works wrong? I mean why use `as.character` function? I used `as.numeric(mdf$Rank)` but it still not work well. Thanks!

Comment: It's because the conversion of factors to numerics doesn't work well in R so you have to turn them to characters first.

Comment: See ?factor. Better to explicitly use numeric or ordered factor. Use as.numeric(levels(mdf$Rank)[mdf$Rank]) rather than as.character, but again best to fix this where the data are created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the answer you are looking for, use:

```
mdf[order(as.numeric(as.character(mdf$Rank))),]
```

The reason your original code doesn't work is that your `Rank` variable is a factor, so it will be sorted by the levels of the factor.  For example, if you had a data frame such that:

```
DF
#    x
# 1  2
# 2 22
# 3 11
# 4  1
```

and order the data

```
DF[order(DF$x),]
```

and you look at the levels:

```
levels(DF$x)
#   [1] "1"  "2"  "11" "22"
```

We can reorder the levels such that

```
levels(DF$x) <- relevel(DF$x, ref = '11')
```

Now,

```
levels(DF$x)
# [1] "2"  "22" "11" "1"
```

So ordering with the new factor levels we get different results:

```
DF[order(DF$x),]
```

To answer your question of why `as.numeric` doesn't work, it's because each factor level has an associated integer, which you get with `as.numeric`. If you want the number that is the factor label, you must first convert to a character and then convert to numeric, thus requiring `as.numeric(as.character(x))`

For example, calling `as.numeric(DF$x)` gives the integer values for each level, but not the actual label for each level:

```
# [1] 2 4 3 1
```

One way to avoid this in the future if you are loading your data frame from a .csv file is to use `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, or also I like the `fread` function in `data.table` which uses safer default types.

Comment: Thanks! Can you kindly explain this line: `levels(DF$x) <- relevel(DF$x, ref = '11')` I don't understand parameter `ref` though I saw many examples to do so.